# How to view the history of changed values in a table?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table (MYAPPTABLE):

```
--------------------------------------------------
| ColumnName        | Column Type                 |
--------------------------------------------------
| IdApp             | INT  (PK)                   |
 --------------------------------------------------
| NameApp           | NVARCHAR(50)                |
--------------------------------------------------
```

My purpose is to see the change history (Insert, Update, Delete) made on the records of the table, example:

Making an insert:

```
INSERT INTO MYAPPTABLE (NAMEAPP) VALUES ('StackOverFlowApp')
```

Making a UPDATE:

```
UPDATE MYAPPTABLE SET NAMEAPP = 'StackOverFlowAppV2' WHERE NAMEAPP = 'StackOverFlowApp'
```

What I would like to see in a history Select:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| IdApp             | NameApp                     |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1                 | StackOverFlowApp            |
 --------------------------------------------------
| 1                 | StackOverFlowAppV2          |
--------------------------------------------------
```

the first row is the insert, and the second is after update.

But if I do this using **change tracking**, the only thing that throws me is that rows were modified (table version), but no history values ​​modified.

My purpose can be accomplished with any tool SQL Server, or would have to handle it manually?

Comment: You should create a copy of your main table and write a trigger that updates this copy everytime a change occurs in the main table

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Here, found a reference for you: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/091901-1.shtml

Comment: sql server 2014 enterprise

Comment: the Trigger and second table is my last option :P

Comment: How you done [this](https://www.google.be/search?q=sql+server+change+tracking&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=vCMKWPD9McvG8AeM_oDoAw) already?